# Recurrent form submission on the same page using Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest

I have a page with two sections: the first section is a form and the second shows the response of the form when submitted. The form accepts images from an attached webcam. As a result I have to use the Webcam js wrapper from: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs
The form submission needs to be a recurring process, that implies, once a form is submitted, the second section displays the form results and the same page needs to be used to submit the form again.
I'm using Spring Boot/Thymeleaf to accomplish this. Part of my code is as follows:

**form.html**

```
<form name="mainform"   action="">
   <input  type="text" name="sbid[]" id="sbid">
   <td><input type="submit" value="Compare"  onclick="submit_snapshot()"/></td>
</form>
<div id="resdiv">
   <div><img src="images/imgnew.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="220" /></div>
   <p> This is part of the second div</p>
</div>
<script>
   function submit_snapshot() {
   url=url+'sbid[]='+batchId[i].value;
   //alert(url);
   var batchId=document.getElementsByName('sbid[]');
   var url='/imagecompare-0.1.0/compare?';
   for(var i=0; i<batchId.length-1; i++){
   url=url+'sbid[]='+batchId[i].value+'&';
   }

   Webcam.upload( webcamuri, url, function(code, text) {
   document.write(text);
   } );

   }
</script>
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/compare")
public String handleCompare(@RequestParam("sbid[]") String sbid[],
    @RequestParam("webcam[]") MultipartFile webcamFiles[],
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) throws IOException {

    return "formresults";
}
```

The formresults page is almost the same as form.html except that the second div named resdiv has a different data:

```
<div id="resdiv">
    <div><img src="images/imgnew.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="220" /></div>
    <p> This is part of the result div</p>
</div>
```

However, this design does not seem to work. The form submission from form.html properly redirects to formresults and displays the data. However if i perform a subsequent form request from the formresults page, it does not display a correct form response. Instead it is automatically redirected back to form.html.
Could someone help in pointing out why this behaviour is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this issue. The problem here was the following statement:

```
<form name="mainform"   action="">
```

Since the form is being submitted separately by XHR, this blank `action` tag forces the page to return to the earlier page.
I tried removing the `form` tag altogether and now it is working.